# Given a value, can you return a series of rows ignoring blanks but including duplicates?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have one sheet that looks similar to this:

[image]

I would like a formula that will allow me to provide a value from row 1, then remove all blank rows and give me column A and the corresponding column to my selection. Note that values in column A may sometimes be duplicates. Here are some examples of what results might look like:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({A1:A, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,         MATCH("dog", 1:1, 0))&":"&
                             ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A), MATCH("dog", 1:1, 0)))}, 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Two questions - can headers be excluded as well? As of now the formula above gives me Dog in one of the rows as well.
Also - any row that does not begin with a number is returning blanks. Is there any way to include the dashes and A0/B0 selections as well? Example spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12j1Nn91032lp-NCvGmiDvGsuQzgO87p2uNsGM0Dp83s

Comment: @Falcon4ch sure, see your updated sheet/answer

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry to be a pain but if I try to use this formula with references to other sheets it gives me either a circular dependency error or "Query completed with an empty output." I've updated Sheet2 in the above example to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option on the new tab in your shared sheet called MK.idea:

```
=FILTER(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"|"&B2:F),"|",0,0),FLATTEN(B1:F1&(B2:F<>""))=(I1&TRUE))
```